# What's the grammatical role of the marked words?

Tags: grammar

1- We Just couldn't imagine [Gerry] singing in public.

2- They didn't want [anybody] to know their secret.

3- Would you like [me] to lend you some money?

I think they're the second subject, But I don't think these sentences have more than one clause. Is it possible to introduce the main clause with two subjects?

[Cambridge - Verb Patterns](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns-verb-infinitive-or-verb-ing)

> New subject before -ing.
> Some of these verbs (e.g. can’t stand, dislike, imagine, involve, mind, miss, put off and risk) can be used with a new subject before the -ing form (underlined in the examples below). If the new subject is a pronoun, it is in the object form (me, him, her, us, them): We just couldn’t imagine Gerry singing in public.

Answer (score 2):

This is a catenative construction, with the verb in the main clause  ("imagine", "want", or "like") followed by a non-finite clause, the  gerund-participle "singing", or the infinitives "to know", or "to lend".

Your grammar book notes that the subject in these non-finite clauses in such catenative constructions is given in the object form.  In formal style, the subject of gerund-participles may also be possessive (... imagine Gerry's singing...)

So these sentences have (at least) two clauses.  But the second clause is non-finite. The word "Gerry" is only the subject of non-finite clause.